# mi pdf no me muestra mi imagen php

Tags: javascript, php, html

estoy tratabdo de hacer un pdf con una imagen de logo que quiero que se vea en cada pagina el problema es que me aparece asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que no la encuentra
y si se ve bien cuando quito el codigo que imprime el pdf es decir sin la impresion pdf si me la muestra y no tiene problemas ni ningun detalle

adjunto codigo solo de la parte importante de la imagen

estoy usando dompdf mismo que una vez use hace poco y si me funciono peero ya no

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">


<style>
    @page { margin: 180px 50px; }
    header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: orange; text-align: center; }
    #footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: lightblue; }
    #footer .page:after { content: counter(page, upper-roman); }
  </style>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<?php 
include("configuracion.php");
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
ob_start();




?>

<center>
<h2 >CONVENIO DE VENTA EN LÍNEA</h2></center>

<div style="text-align: justify; padding:70px;">

<header>

<img src="logo.png" width="150px" >
</header>
<br><br>Convenio de Venta en línea que celebran por una parte <b>EDITORIAL DELTI, S. A. de C. V.</b>, que en lo sucesivo se denominará como <b>“EDITORIAL DELTI”</b>, representada en este acto por Alba Rosa Vargas Ovalle, en su carácter de Representante Legal, y por la otra
    <?php
               $codigo=ob_get_clean();
               $dompdf = new Dompdf();
               ini_set("memory_limit", "32M");
               $dompdf->load_html($codigo, 'UTF-8');
               $dompdf->setPaper('letter', 'A4');
               ob_end_clean();
               $dompdf->render();
               $pdf=$dompdf->output();
               $dompdf->stream("Talon_de_pago_'".$_SESSION['usuario']."'.pdf",array("Attachment"=> 0 ));

               ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ha intentado poner el `src` de la imagen de forma absoluta y no relativa? depronto eso ayude

Comment: a ya pero la imagen si ma la muestra sin el codigo de impresion de pdf

Comment: <img src="/logo.png" width="150px" >

Answer (score 2):

Puede poner la url absoluta de la imagen en el `src`

O puede agregar en el header el root de su sitio

```
<base href="http://sudominio.com">
```

O puede intentar setear las propiedades en dompdf:

```
$dompdf->setProtocol('http://');
$dompdf->setBaseHost('sudominio.com');
$dompdf->setBasePath('/sub/dir');
```

Para que asi dompdf pueda determinar la url correcta del archivo

Comment: pero si es local?

Comment: @SLOKERMENDOZA, no importa si se trata de un servidor local, domPDF tratará de leer la imagen e integrarla en el documento y, para eso, necesita la ruta absoluta.

Comment: seria esta <base href="http://sudominio.com">
?

Comment: o cual puedo tomar

Comment: Y no puede entonces ponerle la ruta en localhost? Algo como http://localhost (pero eso ya depende de como tenga montado el servidor)