# me aperece imagen no encontrada en mi pdf php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

estoy tratando de generar un pdf con imgen la cuestion es que no me muestra la imagen o me la muestra de la siguiente forma

aca esta mi pedazo de codigo solo donde muestrao la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<img src="images/logo.png" width="150px" >

<center>
<h2 >CONVENIO DE VENTA EN LÍNEA</h2></center>

<div style="text-align: justify; padding:70px;">

<?php
               $codigo=ob_get_clean();
               $dompdf = new Dompdf(array('enable_remote' => true));

               ini_set("memory_limit", "32M");
               $dompdf->load_html($codigo, 'UTF-8');
               $dompdf->setPaper('letter', 'A4');
               ob_end_clean();
               $dompdf->render();
               $pdf=$dompdf->output();
               $dompdf->stream("CONVENIO DE VENTA EN LÍNEA'".$usuario."'.pdf",array("Attachment"=> 0 ));

               ?>

</body>
</html>
```

lo qu necesito es que la imagen me la muestre pero no me la muestre y este mismo que s epueda aplicar a varios heders de encabezado cuadno cambia de hoja

Comment: Ya hay otra pregunta con la misma imagen. Es un deber? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/451471/mi-pdf-no-me-muestra-mi-imagen-php

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [mi pdf no me muestra mi imagen php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/451471/mi-pdf-no-me-muestra-mi-imagen-php)

Comment: trate eso pero no me enruto bien

Comment: y me aparece el mismo error de imagen no encontrada

Comment: Recortas la imagen. Qué sentido tiene hacer la misma pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

```
function imageBase64($path){
  $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  $arrContextOptions=array("ssl"=>array(
          "verify_peer"=>false,
          "verify_peer_name"=>false,
      ),introducir el código aquí
  );  

  $data = file_get_contents($path,false,stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
  return 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
  //$base64 = 'data:' . mime_content_type($name) . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data)
}
```

Mira lo que devuelve esta función lo penes en el src de la etiqueta img y listo

Answer (score -1):

Puedes intentar poner la url absoluta, el error en si es un 404, que no encuentra tu imagen, si esto no funciona prueba convertir la imagen a base64 ya que a Dompdf no le gustan las urls y las rutas

Comment: que tal lo agrege asi pero no me lo muestra <base href="http://localhost:81/convenio/images/logo.png" width="150px">

Comment: Eso hace referencia a localhost. En general eso no te va a producir una salida con la imagen. Lo suyo, como dice @Daniel es convertir la imagen en base64 e "incrustar la" en el PDF. Busca más información al respecto, creo recordar que dompdf te lo permitia

Comment: ya lo hice pero me manda esto iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABUEAAAP7CAYAAAB1GU+JAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAAuIwAALiMBeKU/dgAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAACAASURBVHic7N17nJx1fff/9+ea3WwSCAJCkp

Comment: $rutaImagen = __DIR__ . "/images/logo.png";
$contenidoBinario = file_get_contents($rutaImagen);
$imagenComoBase64 = base64_encode($contenidoBinario);
echo $imagenComoBase64;

Comment: como se puede editar eso?

Comment: are otra pregunta gracias